# how to use js files in my asp.net mvc view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am new in MVC, I have learned it is better to keep javascript separated from view as much as possible. I am trying to do so, for example I have created a different javascript file to create a grid, but what is the best way to call it?

I am now doing it like this:

```
function createDynamicGrid(gridId, source, column) {   
    chartId.kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: source,
        },
        height: 350,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        columns: column
    });
}
```

i use it in my view like this:

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/CreateGrid.js")"></script>
```

here is my html:

```
 <div id="grid" style="height:200px"></div>
```

In my view I do ajax call, I get the result and I pass it to this js file to give me back a grid. Now my question is, is it a correct way? Or should I call this js file differently:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("dataForGrid","Dashbrd")",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        var clmns = [
            { field: "TurbineName", title: "Turbine" },
            { field: "ProductionValue", title: "Production" },
            { field: "WindSpeed", title: "Wind Speed" },
        ];
        //Create Dynamic grid
        createDynamicGrid($("#gridProAvail"), result.rsltGridPro, clmns);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is fine, you can always hit your JS function using AJAX as they are just some function residing in the different file, there is no problem with calling the functions in separate JS files as long as they are not too tightly coupled.

You, however, need to put in some checks regarding, on error what would you do and if no data is provided, how are you going to hit the function in your external script.

Comment: but if want to create a javascript file for every different need,one for charts one for grids,one for buttons,....then loads of javascripts sources i have to add up in my view page,is not that problematic?

Comment: You don't need to create a lot of javascript files you keep your code in ONE SEPARATE FILE for every piece of functionality so to keep the logic and code segregated. name it as custom.js maybe that is your own pre-written functions that can be used to return the desired data with parameters